# How to typecast correctly

Tags: c

I have trouble with typecasting in calculations. sometimes I don't have the result, I expect. Is there any documentation how correctly to do typecasting or is there a rule of thumb.
 Thanks!

examples of my problem:

```
int i=50000; 
long l; 
l=i*10; 
int i = 10; 
float f; 
f=i/12;
```

Comment: "is there any documentation" -- goodness, yes!  Start with [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) or [the standard itself](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf).

Comment: @Brian Oh lord, the standard is the very last place to look. You only start looking at the standard once you've learnt the language to a high level. Anyone that hasn't yet learnt about integer vs floating point divide (and we were all there once) will have no chance of getting anything useful out of the standard. Have you ever spoken to a novice programmer?!!

Comment: hah, indeed.  it was a little tongue-in-cheek. but you're right.

Comment: That said, one of the "rules" you'll probably want to learn is to avoid typecasting as much as possible - it is sometimes necessary, but often indicates code that could be designed/written better, and is unfortunately too often just used blindly to "get the right result" without bothering to understand what was really going on... In your particular example, I might suggest `long l = i; l *= 10;` and `float f = i; f /= 12;` but there are other ways as well, depending on what your real code looks like...